# How to dispose Flutter google map's controller

Tags: flutter, google-maps-flutter

I was using [google_maps_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/google_maps_flutter) library in my project. While i hot reload the map or back to map from another view then it crashes with message :

```
Exception has occurred.
PlatformException (PlatformException(error, java.lang.IllegalStateException: Trying to create an already created platform view, view id: 0
    at io.flutter.plugin.platform.PlatformViewsController$1.createPlatformView(PlatformViewsController.java:85)
    at io.flutter.embedding.engine.systemchannels.PlatformViewsChannel$1.create(PlatformViewsChannel.java:96)
```

So i was trying to dispose the map and its controller. i got a code snippet to dispose [in this article](https://medium.com/pharos-production/using-google-maps-on-flutter-for-android-d62b724d86b9) 
So i added this code snippet:

```
@override
  void dispose() {
    _disposeController();
    super.dispose();
  }

  Future<void> _disposeController() async{
    final GoogleMapController controller = await _controller.future;
    //controller.dispose();
  }
```

but uncommenting last line was giving this error:

```
 The method 'dispose' isn't defined for the class 'GoogleMapController'.
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'dispose'.
```

then how can i dispose the controller?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I just faced the same trouble and realized, that they drastically changed the GoogleMapController implementation between this medium article and the current version.

Also, the readme on the package could be outdated, I used the examples from the package itself:

e.g.
https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/master/packages/google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter/example/lib/animate_camera.dart

They seem to work really well.

**Update**

It seems like they have gotten rid of the Completer way and in their examples they do not need this construction anymore.

That means:
Use the GoogleMapController directly without a completer:

```
GoogleMapController mapController;
// instead of 
// GoogleMapController mapController;
```

just assign to this variable onMapCreated:

```
onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) {
  _controller.complete(controller);
},
```

You can then use this controller without awaiting the future.

```
mapController.animateCamera(
  CameraUpdate.newLatLng(
    const LatLng(56.1725505, 10.1850512),
  ),
);
```

I have not seen any need to dispose this instance, it is not implemented anymore through the ChangeNotifier() class.

Comment: While external links are good references to support your answer, please also include the working snippet in the body of your answer. This way your answer remains helpful in the future if the external links get broken.

Comment: But it is not serving my purpose. because  the platform exception is happening

Comment: There is simply no dispose on the implementation of this controller. I don't know if dipose is necessary there at all.

Comment: @Muhammad Noman could you please update the code I don't understand where is the _controller. please give the complete code or link

Comment: Hi @Abhiram, this is mapController, not _controller, this is a typo. I am not able to edit the answer as it is too old now. Making the correction here. Thanks